# Metro application, printer ui and installation process

Tags: printing, windows-installer, microsoft-metro

I have an EXE-file for installing a printer driver. If I pack this file into MSI-package (with using WiX Toolset) and install than all is fine and Windows Edge (and other Metro apps) prints correctly on the installed device.

When I install the printer driver directly by calling the EXE-file than printer installs correctly for non-metro apps and metro apps doesn't recognize printer driver ("We couldn't reach this printer. Make sure the printer is on and you are connected to the printer's network, or try a different printer").

What can cause this behavior? Have tested on Windows 10x64.